# Conditional probability question for n trials`

Tags: probability, probability-theory

E and F are mutually exclusive events, trials are independent and performed repeatedly. I have already calculated the probability E or F occurs for the first time on the nth trial.

The question is:

What is the conditional probability that E occurs for the first time on the nth trial given that the event E or F occurs for the first time on the nth trial?

I think that the way this question is phrased, I can take as given that E or F occured for the first time on the nth trial, so my answer should intuitively be:
$\frac{P(E)}{P(E)+P(F)}$
But my friend is arguing that the probability of the event E or F occuring for the first time on the nth trial should be included in the conditional probability. I think he is right, but am confused about why my answer is wrong.

edit: Here is the verbatim phrasing:
What is the conditional probability that the event E occurs for the first time on the nth trial, given that
event $E \cup F$ occurs for the first time on the nth trial?

edit 2: alternate answer given is $\frac{(1-P(E))^{n-1}P(E}{(1-P(E)-P(F))^{n-1}(P(E)+P(F))}$ which I don't believe makes sense thinking about it more. For starters, why would adding uncertainty in the n-1 trials lead to my answer, which assumes these are determined, being multiplied by something larger than 1.

Comment: I think your answer is not wrong, One can use a longer  conditional probability calculation that uses the first time stuff. A related question was asked today, but the answer does not go into detail about the probability you ask about.

Comment: Is the condition, the event $E\cup F$ occurs for the first time on the $n$th trial, or is the condition that either $E$ occurs for the first time or $F$ occurs for the first time on the $n$th trial?

Comment: Kevin- i'm not sure I see how those are distinct? André, I guess this is where my question is, what is probabilistic about the first n-1 events? it seems from the wording this is determined

Comment: @qbert The first condition (which is what you edited in) is that neither $E$ nor $F$ occurs for the first $n-1$ trials, then one of them occurs on the $n$th trial. The second condition considers two possibilities- either $E$ does not occur for the first $n-1$ trials, but $F$ might, and $E$ occurs on the $n$th trial (this is $E$ occurs for the first time on the $n$th trial), or $F$ does not occur for the first $n-1$ trials, but $E$ might, and $F$ occurs on the $n$th trial (this is $F$ occurs on the $n$th trial). Whenever the first applies, the second does too, but not necessarily vice versa.

Comment: In my edit, i just replaced "or" with $\cup$ which is equivalent. I am not following the logic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_i, F_i$ be the event that $E, F$ occurs in the $i$-th trial respectively, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$. Maybe your friend is considering this:

$$\begin{align} & P\left(E_n \Bigg| (E_n \cup F_n) \cap
\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} (E_i^c \cap F_i^c) \right) \\
=&~ \frac {\displaystyle 
P\left(E_n \cap (E_n \cup F_n) \cap 
\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} (E_i^c \cap F_i^c)\right)} 
{\displaystyle P\left((E_n \cup F_n) \cap 
\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} (E_i^c \cap F_i^c)\right) }
\end{align}$$

Assuming that performed repeatedly means that those trials are independent, this reduced to

$$ \frac {\displaystyle 
P(E_n \cap (E_n \cup F_n)) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} P(E_i^c \cap F_i^c)} 
{\displaystyle P(E_n \cup F_n) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} P(E_i^c \cap F_i^c) }
= \frac {P(E_n)} {P(E_n) + P(F_n)}
$$

Usually people familiar with this will know the independence and directly skip this.

Comment: Do you mean $E_{i}$ is the probability it occurs for the first time on the ith trial?

Comment: Occur, not necessary to be the first time.